# iOS - Image Management with CGImageRetain and CGImageRelease

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have the Obj-C code in my iOS app:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageRetain([self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer]);
if(_delegate) {
  [_delegate sessionWithPresentedFrame:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]];
}
CGImageRelease( cgImage );
```

I copied this code from a blog, and I need to understand a bit about the memory management (which I currently don't). So I'm hoping that somebody could help me out.

Now, `cgImage` is clearly retained. Then it is passed off to `[_delegate sessionWithPresentedFrame:]`.

Then `cgImage` is released. My question is whether or not releasing `cgImage` here is safe. Since I pass it off to `[_delegate sessionWithPresentedFrame:]`, would releasing it here kill it when it's in use inside `[_delegate sessionWithPresentedFrame:]`?

Should I remove the `CGImageRelease( cgImage );` here and add it after `cgImage` is done being used in `[_delegate sessionWithPresentedFrame:]`?

Or do I have this backwards?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're thinking is overly complex. The code is correct. It is the delegates responsibility to retain the UIImage if it needs to. This is separate from the cgImage management anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe. If th method sessionWithPresentedFrame: does need to retain the image, then it will do. Not our problem in this part of code.